# how to make repetitive request of the input?

Tags: python, for-loop

I write this code to get the of digit of the number inputted by the user

the problem I don't know how to make it repetitive to user to get the request of entering the input again and again

```
x=input("enter the number you want to get the sum of its' sum: ")
z=0
for a in x:
    z=z+int(a)
print(z)
```

Comment: Please try to think about the problem logically. See how the code `z=z+int(a)` happens multiple times? Why does that happen? (Hint: is it inside the loop, or outside? How do you know? What is the purpose of loops?) Therefore, if you want the code that gets the user's input to happen multiple times, should it be inside the loop, or outside? How do you do that? Which code gets the user's input? Therefore, what do you need to change? Can you solve the problem now?

Comment: Try a guide on [loops in Python](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-python/amp/).